# Is there anyway to parse & exract the image which is "hidden" on the website?

Tags: python, image, web-scraping

Currently I'm having a problem to parse & extract an image from a "Manga" website using python.

The image info was nowhere to be found if I using "View Page Source" but it can be locate if I using "Inspect" on the chrome browser.

I'm quite new to programming & html stuff, hope that somebody here can enlighten me on my problem.

I have attached a picture of the "html" which I have problem extract & parse which I cannot seems to understand why I cannot extract it.

Picture of the html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/58tpi.jpg

The website link: http://www.dm5.com/m4761/

Hope that somebody can guide me on this, thanks.

Comment: the page is dynamic, meaning that data is rendered after the initial html request. You'll have to use something like Selenium to first render the page, and then you can pull the html that includes what you are looking for

Comment: just keep practising. It's tricky at first, but once you see a bunch of different examples, you'll start to identify what you need to do and when to do it. Some sites are easy, some are tough, but all learning experiences

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks for your help on this "tricky" problem & the solutions works great. Will keep practice & polishing my skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get that using Selenium:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

url='http://www.dm5.com/m4761'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')

for image in images:
    print (image['src'])

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/dm5/images/mrtx.gif
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/manhua_pc_code_1.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/loading.gif
http://manhua1003-104-250-139-218.cdndm5.com/h/海贼王[one_piece]/海贼王[one_piece]vol1/op01-001.jpg?cid=4761&key=82513c5daf34874acd278fdccbe71fa7&uk=
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/dm5/images/mrtx.gif
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://manhua1028-104-250-150-11.cdndm5.com/userfile/6/avatars/old/10084531/20150224002025_64x64.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/user/toux3.jpg
http://manhua1028-104-250-150-11.cdndm5.com/userfile/5/avatars/2018/2/3/1531451/1/84138ab1414e451cb12336f97d3c0ed2_tmb_64x64.jpg
http://tvax3.sinaimg.cn/default/images/default_avatar_female_50.gif
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/dm5/images/mrtx.gif
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/view_code_ad.jpg
http://mhfm7218us.cdndm5.com/15/14569/20141224141557_130x174_11.jpg
http://mhfm9218us.cdndm5.com/38/37728/20170728093236_130x174_14.jpg
http://s3m.milkjpg.com/galileo/687829-053047751d43c07835a73de22c69ca32.jpg
http://mhfm3218us.cdndm5.com/17/16932/20141204115525_130x174_27.jpg
http://mhfm6218us.cdndm5.com/7/6147/20190110220700_130x174_15.jpg
http://mhfm1218us.cdndm5.com/37/36470/20170516144045_130x174_12.jpg
http://mhfm2218us.cdndm5.com/44/43853/20180804103210_130x174_13.jpg
http://mhfm6218us.cdndm5.com/12/11320/11320_c.jpg
http://p1.qhimgs3.com/t018026871eaaa66db6.gif
http://mhfm1218us.cdndm5.com/37/36623/20170525102253_130x174_14.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/cross_red.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/manhua_pc_code_1.png
http://mhfm6218us.cdndm5.com/34/33771/20180727110326_130x174.jpg
http://mhfm2218us.cdndm5.com/47/46961/20181221164141_130x174.jpg
http://mhfm5218us.cdndm5.com/42/41712/20180620114227_130x174.jpg
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/logo-big.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/down-qrcode-2.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/weibo.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/account-icon-facebook.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/account-icon-vk.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/account-icon-ok.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/account-icon-instagram.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/account-icon-twitter.png
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/account-icon-rss.png
```

If you need to limit your search:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

url='http://www.dm5.com/m4761'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

alpha = soup.find_all('div', {'id':'cp_img'})

for each in alpha:
    for image in each.find_all('img'):
        print (image['src'])

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
http://css122us.cdndm5.com/v201904041843/dm5/images/loading.gif
http://manhua1003-104-250-139-218.cdndm5.com/h/海贼王[one_piece]/海贼王[one_piece]vol1/op01-001.jpg?cid=4761&key=82513c5daf34874acd278fdccbe71fa7&uk=
```